# Flutter Native Splash Screen image not appearing - Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, splash-screen

I added Flutter Native Splash screen to my `dependencies`. The color appears with no problem but the image is not appearing and I don't know why.

`Pubspec.yaml`:

```
  #flutter native splash
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets\RoderLogoo.png
  color: "#2A52BE"

  android: true
  ios: true
  web: true
```

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

The image does exist, I've tried using every possible size of the image possible, the size I am using right now is `192x162`
The image is transparent but I don't think that has to do with anything. the path is correct (the file where I store all my photos is `assets`.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you testing with android 12? and what do you mean by "the image is transparent"?

Comment: you are using backslash "\", but you have to use forward slash "/" in the image path.

Comment: I have made the changes but it still doesn't work, the image does exist, i am spelling it correct, I have made the changes that you have suggested but it still doesn't work

Comment: I am not using android 12 and by "the image is transparent" i mean that the background is transparent

Comment: Are you certain that the image file is named exactly as specified in your pubspec.yaml file?  You didn't accidentally type an extra o?  The file isn't actually named RoderLogo.png is it?  Also, are you running  "flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create" after you change that part of your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: YES, i am doing both of the suggestions 100%, the extra o is just because i have 30 versions of the same image with different sizes

Comment: The original Flutter logo is always returning even if i don't specify `image` should i remove it some how?

Comment: when i changed the mipmap flutter images to my own images the flutter native splash screen is returning those images, but i never specify those images, how can i fix this

Answer (score 4):

As in your question, can find problem.

As first for `flutter_native_splash` you used wrong slag. Actually must use forward slag like in the comment that @Shivam Jamaiwar said.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/RoderLogoo.png
  color: "#2A52BE"
```

As second you should use specific image file name rather than directory name in yaml file. Like that. Because sometime image without specific name can't load from assets file.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/RoderLogoo.png
```

**Edit:** **Procedure to add and fix**

1. Create specific yaml file with the name of `flutter_native_splash.yaml` in the root directory and copy&paste code from documentation.
2. Create assets folder and add your image to that directory.
3. In the `flutter_native_splash.yaml` file you need to setting up to appear your image on native splash screen. But as documentation **“Only one parameter can be used, color and background_image cannot both be set.”** So add setting for image like that
   `background_image: "assets/splash_image.jpg"`.
4. And run `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create` and `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create --flutter_native_splash.yaml`.
5. Then run your project again. That will fine for you and not anything to do other. But you need to add some setting for Android 12 and other platform beside the android.

Comment: I have made the changes but it still doesn't work, the image does exist, i am spelling it correct, I have made the changes that you have suggested but it still doesn't work and i did run Flutter clean then flutter pub get then flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create

Comment: The original Flutter logo is always returning even if i don't specify `image` should i remove it some how?

Comment: when i changed the mipmap flutter images to my own images the flutter native splash screen is returning those images, but i never specify those images, how can i fix this

Comment: Did you forgot to add for android 12 specific?
```android_12:
    image: assets/images/RoderLogoo.png
    icon_background_color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/RoderLogoo.png
    icon_background_color_dark: "#121212"
```
Like that.

Comment: Hay. I edit my comment for procedure to fix that. Try again that procedure.

Answer (score 1):

for path add " / " not this " \ "

flutter_native_splash:

image: "assets/RoderLogoo.png"

color: "#2A52BE"

android: true

ios: true

then you need to run three commands after saving your yaml file

**run following commands:**

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create